# Communication between navigation controller and container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

```
      Parent
  View Controller
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |       Navigation Cont.
|_________________|      _________________
|                 |     |                 |
|                 |     |                 |
| Container View  | --> |                 |  -->  Child View Controllers 
|                 |     |                 |
|_________________|     |_________________|
```

My app has a navigation structure composed by a parent view controller and a container that contains a navigation controller (and its child view controllers). The problems is that during the initialisation of these child View Controllers I want to pass some values provided by the Parent View controller. Unfortunately the method `prepareForSegue` used in the parent only detects the container segue but its not called when the child view controllers are changing.

How could this problem be addressed? I'm using Swift but I also understand Objective-C.

Comment: I would use the delegate pattern.

Comment: So far I tried delegates but I could only pass values Container --> Parent, not Parent --> Container as I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the end it took time... but I finally got it. 
It's simple: the child will talk with the parent over `self.parentview.parentview`. A couple of delegates and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepareforsegue` like,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
    [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
}
}
```

you can do this from container viewcontroller

```
 NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
 UIViewController *rootViewController = (UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2]; //index of your root viewcontroller
```

and refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763457/how-do-i-pass-data-from-my-viewcontroller-to-a-container-view) for pass data to `containerview's VC'

Comment: Thanks, but I stated before that prepareForSegue is only called once when the Container is loaded, the problem resides when the there is any changes in the navigationcontroller inside the container, as the prepareforsegue method in the parent is not being called.